# Google Play rejects my RN app because of location

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-play

I've been facing an issue for a few days now. Everytime I submit my release to Google Play Store, I get a message saying my app has been rejected over and over again. I tried multiple things.

First I tried removing the permissions from my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.lachariottenative">
 <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Then I tried editing my app.json file and set permissions to an empty array but each time I get the same error when uploading my app to the Google Play Store. It says that I'm using background location although I am not.

Can you help please?
Thanks in advance

EDIT : I do not wish to use location in my app for the moment. But somehow it still asks for permissions...

Comment: May be you have to remove functionalities as well from your app related to *background location* and also if you want to use background location you need to submit permission declaration form on play console and submit it for their review.

Comment: I got that but no feature in my app uses background location nor any sort of location. None of my package should be using location, this is weird.

Comment: Then you should also update the open and closed testing tracks if you are having with that build which you are submitting in production. make sure to update them as well.

Comment: if you want to fetch user location in background you have to run the foreground service, or use job scheduler service https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler

Comment: I do not want to fetch user location at all, not background nor foreground. I am not using location in my app. And I have no testing tracks. Everything should be ok but for some reason, it still requires location permissions.